# Count number of vertex disjoint paths

Tags: combinatorics

Could someone please help solve this problem?

> Count the number of triples $(p_0; p_1; p_2)$, where $p_i$ are vertex-disjoint lattice paths of length 6 from $A_i = (i; 2-i)$ to $B_i = (3 + i; 5-i)$.

I really stuck with the solution and would appreciate any help. Thank you!